# In cytoscapejs, how can I get element style from a collection?

Tags: cytoscape.js

My goal is to get the styles for an element.

Actually my true goal is to read the graph out of CytoscapeJS and then feed it back into Cytoscape.  To do that I need to be able to get the element styles out.

When I try to get element style for each element, it returns all the possible styles:

For example:

```
const selectedNodeInMaster = cy.getElementById(getSelectedNodeId)
const nhood = selectedNodeInMaster.closedNeighborhood();
const foo = nhood.map((el) => {
    const foo = {data: el.data(), id: el.id(), style: el.style(), classes: el.classes()}
    console.log(foo)
    return foo
})
```

Here is the result of the code above:

[image]

If however I do:

```
cy.json({flatEles: true})
```

Then I can see the style data I need at this location:

```
_private.elements[0]._private.style
```

As shown here:

[image]

Comment: instead of for each element one by one you can get whole styles as JSON with `cy.style().json()`. Note that functional styles can not be converted to JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

I think cytoscape is doing well because if you are calling me the node style, no metter if, for example, you set just only the z-index, because that node have also a color, a border-color, .... even if they are default values.
So if you ask me for the style I will return all the properties on that node.

Now we come to your problem, for obvious reasons you cannot use the values ​​inside the _private parameter.

You need a subset of the properties of the style object, and you also know what are this properties because you set the style data before insert data in cytoscape.
Than you can store all the style attributes name in an array and then say to cytoscape to return just only that attributes from a node.

you can take a property value in two ways:

1. `node.style(propertyName)`
2. `const styleObj = node.style(); and then styleObj[propertyName];`

I hope I have understood the question and also to it well